# HMR stops working and vue-loader hangs with first compiler issue

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-loader

When i get a compile error HMR stops working for me.
It hangs with this message, and any subsequent changes to a file don't update the page (with HMR)

```
 WAIT  Compiling...                                                                                                                                                                                            
40% building 1/3 modules 2 active ...node_modules\vue-loader\lib\index.js??vue-loader-options!
```

It just remains stuck like this... If I don't create any compile issue HMR works fine, but as soon as i make a compile error it stays like this, and HMR no longer works unless i restart `npm run serve`

Any ideas what to try?

I have tried removing node modules and reinstalling, but that doesn't help.